# log4j writes to Systemerr.log on Websphere (configuration from java )

Tags: java, logging, log4j, websphere

I have a web application, which uses log4j and slf4j as facade for logging. Logging is configured not from log4j.properties file, but from Java code.
Application is running on three different machines using Websphere Application Server.

Issue is that on two instances logging works as expected. But on the third one nothing is written in my logfile. Output goes to SystemErr.log instead (there are messages of ERROR and INFO levels).

Initially I thought that something is with Websphere server configuration, but later I found this link http://www.webagesolutions.com/knowledgebase/waskb/waskb004/ which says that such situation can be when log4j.properties can not be read.

But I am not using property file for this. And configuration form Java works OK on other two instances.
Any ideas what can be the issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the logging you see on sys.err is the logging from your code? Second, do you see the logging coming on sys.err during the whole lifetime of your application? Because if you configure log4j in code then all logging which happens before the configuration code is executed runs unconfigured and therefore in sys.err.

Comment: Hi Michal!
Yes, logging in SystemErr.log is definitely from my code.
Also logging configuration appears in very beginning of application work. It is in static initializer of Sevlet, which starts on server start up. Application worked actively two days, so there should be something in my log file...
Thank you!

Comment: And you see all the logging output from these two days on sys.err?

Comment: I am not sure if there are 100% logs from these two days, because there are a lot of it. But I can see a lot of logs from today and there were logs from two previous days.
Do you know - is there some configuration in admin console, that can cause such behavior?

Comment: I do not know Websphere. However I do not think it is possible to 'configure' something like that. Any chance that on the CLASSPATH of the third application server instance an alternative slf4j binding exists? Which would win over the log4j one you probably supply with your application? I mean, could it be that in some application server folder  something like slf4j-simple-xxxx.jar exists?

Comment: Hello Michal! You are right! There also is a jar for Simple logging. And SLF4J manual says that it writes into SystemErr.log. I will be able to fix and check it a bit later. But it definitely looks that it was the issue. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If that turns out to be the case, please accept the answer, thanks and best regards, Michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that no alternative slf4j binding (such as [simple](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html)) exists on the CLASSPATH.